# $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ isomorphic as groups?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, proof-verification, vector-spaces, topological-groups

Using the axiom of choice, $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are equal-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$ and so are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces thus as groups.

This is obvious, however I recently began reading Godement's *Introduction à la théorie des groupes de Lie* and in particular I was reading the chapter on topological groups when I came across this statement:

> Given a group $G$, there is at most one topology that makes it into a topological group that is at the same time locally compact and countable to infinity.

(I don't know how to translate "dénombrable à l'infini" better, it means $G$ is a union of countably many compact sets)

Here's my reasoning: let $\phi: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a group isomorphism. In particular, it is a bijection, and so one can define a topology $\mathcal{T}$ such that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism from $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T})$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology.

Obviously, $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T})$ is locally compact and countable to infinity.

Moreover, $+: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, and letting $add$ denote the addition in $\mathbb{R}^2$, because $\phi$ is an isomorphism, we get $+= \phi^{-1}\circ add \circ (\phi\times\phi)$. Therefore, since all these maps are continuous (wrt the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathcal{T}$ on $\mathbb{R}$), so is $+$, and similarly one gets that $x\mapsto -x$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ wrt $\mathcal{T}$.

But then $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T})$ is a locally compact topological group that's countable to infinity: according to Godement's claim $\mathcal{T}$ is the usual topology !

This leads to the absurdity that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are homeomorphic, which is trivially false.

I'm really stuck on this and I don't know where I went wrong. Could anybody please solve my problem?

EDIT : as suggested in the comments, here's a link to a dropbox file with the proof in Godement's book : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2gxg1jpbdmmcg23/AACP__txcn3o26cw-JR5W5Oea?dl=0
Sorry for the quality of the pictures. And it's in french !

Comment: You have refuted that sentence of Godement.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown but he proves it and I think uses it later on, so my first guess would be that I made a mistake somewhere (it seems to be quite a big theorem)

Comment: "Union of countably many compact sets" = $\sigma$-compact.

Comment: @RobertIsrael thanks for the terminology !

Comment: A google search for "dénombrable à l'infini godement" finds a googlebooks extract that includes the relevant parts of the book. I agree with you that this  result looks unbelievable. In your counterexample, Godement's proof needs us to accept that the graph of a group isomorphism between $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}^2$ is a closed subspace of $\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R}^2$. I don't think that can be right.

Comment: @RobArthan : Then I will have to try and look for a mistake in the proof (it's not particularly long - 5/6 pages in total- but I didn't find any in my first reading so it won't be easy)

Comment: @RobArthan and Max: It would be good to have the relevant proof included in the question, in a screenshot, via a link, or otherwise. The theorem can be false, but I'd be more confident claiming that if I saw the proof. (I couldn't find it on Google Books.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta : well Godement states it as a corollary, whose proof is rather short, but he leans on a theorem whose proof is a bit longer. Should I still include the proofs though ?

Comment: @Max I would recommend that. At least I can't judge otherwise. If it feels too long, you can give links to the image files instead of adding them all to the question. I assume you don't want to write up the whole story by hand. But it's your call, of course.

Comment: Here is the [google books link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=-BAnnb7vr9YC&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=dénombrable+à+l'infini+godement&source=bl&ots=9uGEEgo7Of&sig=WYkeW4ce63DewMPoSG5d0dep3fo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQxeOgvr7VAhVQmbQKHfXOBW0Q6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=dénombrable%20à%20l'infini%20godement&f=false) It's Corollaire 2 on page 8. @Max: the proof of the corollary from Corollaire 1 is very short and it is that that I am suspicious of in my comment above.

Comment: It seems I overestimated the length of the proof. I'll provide a dropbox link to a file I created with pictures of the proof (in french)

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/270700/4280 where this idea is also applied to all Euclidean spaces.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma : yes I had this idea as well, but it's way easier to show that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ aren't homeomorphic than for arbitrary $n,m$

Comment: Two topological groups can be both isomorphic as groups and homeomorphic as spaces, but not isomorphic as topological groups.

Comment: There are, nevertheless, theorems of this type, for instance, an abstract isomorphism between two simple Lie groups is necessary smooth.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are correct, and Godement's proof is incorrect.  His proof proceeds by letting $G$ and $G'$ be two different $\sigma$-compact locally compact groups with the same underlying group, and considers the diagonal $D\subseteq G\times G'$.  He then applies a theorem about $\sigma$-compact locally compact groups to the projection maps $D\to G$ and $D\to G'$.  The problem is that the theorem does not apply, since $D$ may not be $\sigma$-compact or locally compact, since it may not be closed in $G\times G'$.

This is exactly what happens in the case of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$: the "diagonal" in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^2$ is the graph of a group-isomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$.  A group-isomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is a horrendously discontinuous map, so its graph is a horrendous non-closed subgroup of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^2$.  (Quick proof that the graph of an isomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ cannot be closed: since $f$ cannot be $\mathbb{R}$-linear, there exists $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)\neq xf(1)$.  But $f(q)=qf(1)$ for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, so by approximating $x$ by rationals, we find that $(x,xf(1))$ is in the closure of the graph of $f$.)

Comment: Godement explicitly states that the diagonal $D\subset G\times G'$ is closed but doesn't say why. This is a good lesson in paying attention to innocent-looking statements.

Comment: Your answer actually begs a question: is there a simpler proof than the one implicit in Godement's (apparently correct) Corollaire 1 that the graph of a group isomorphism between $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}^2$ cannot be closed in $\Bbb{R}^3$? (That concern is why I provided my observation about this problem with Godement's proof as a comment rather than an answer.)

Comment: @RobArthan: Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is an isomorphism, and take any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)\neq xf(1)$.  By approximating $x$ by rationals, $(x,xf(1))$ is in the closure of the graph of $f$.  By a more complicated elaboration of this idea, you can show the graph of $f$ is actually dense in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @EricWofsey: thanks. That argument would be a helpful addition to your answer.

Comment: I see. Indeed, there's no reason that $D$ be closed unless we already assume that the topologies are the same (in which case, it is closed, but then it's not really that useful).

Comment: What's odd is that if I remember correctly he uses the corollary later on, and so I wonder what results still hold and what others don't. Should I (or someone) tell Springer (or someone) about the mistake ?

Comment: What's the procedure here, should I try to contact Springer (the editor of the book) ?

Comment: @Max: Since Godement, sadly, passed away last year, yes, you may want to contact the editorial board of Springer Verlag (Universitext series); just this year they published an English translation of his book. However, first check this edition if the mistake was corrected. Also, consider contacting the translator (at Reims University) instead.