# details in the proof: G a commutative Lie group and $(\pi, V)$ a finite-dim unitary representation of G. Then $\pi$ is irreducible iff dim $V = 1$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, group-actions, topological-groups

I am getting lost at filling in the details in the proof that

**Let G a commutative Lie group and $(\pi, V)$ a finite-dim unitary representation of G. Then
$\pi$ is irreducible iff dim $V = 1$**

I having trouble with $\implies$

Assume $\pi$ is irreducible.
Fix a $g\in G$, I claim that the map $T:V\to V : v \mapsto \pi(g)v$ is an intertwiner from $(V,\pi(g))$ to itself:

- T is linear because $\pi(g)$ is linear.
- The diagram in the definition commutes.
- T is continuous  (**Question1 how do I justify this?**)

(This part in the solution that I have is actually phrased in an odd way: The operator $\pi(g)$ commutes with $\pi(G)\subset Aut(V)$.**How can a  map commute with a  set? A map should commute with another map, otherwise it makes no sense** **Question2 Can you clear this up?**)

So by Schur's lemma, $\exists \lambda_g \in \Bbb C$ s.t $T=\lambda_gId_V$   **Hence span $\pi(G)=\Bbb C Id_V$**

Every linear subspace of V is a subrepresentation. By the irreducibility of V, there are no subrepresentations apart from V and 0. There for V must be one-dimensional.

**Question3 I can't understand this last paragraph, this is my main problem**

Why is every linear subspace of V is a subrepresentation (I assume this follow from the previous paragraphs but I just don't see how)?

Why does the fact that there are no subrepresentations imply that  $V must be one-dimensional ?  No subrepresentations would imply that the are no non trivial subspaces, but then I am just getting a circular argument

---

These are the definitions and theorem that I have:

**Schur's lemma:** If G is a loc compact group; $(\pi, V)$  a cont fin-dim irreducible representation. Then Hom$_G(V,V)=\{$ intertwiners from $(\pi,V)$ to itself  $\}=\Bbb C Id_V$

**Intertwiner:** An intertwiner between 2 representations $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ is a continuous linear map $T:V_1 \to V_2$ s.t. the diagram commutes for every $h \in G$:

$$\begin{array} .V_1 & \stackrel{T}{\longrightarrow} & V_2 \\
\downarrow{\pi_1(h)} & & \downarrow{\pi_2(h)} \\
V_1 & \stackrel{T}{\longrightarrow} & V_2  
\end{array}
$$

**Subrepresentation** or invariant subspace of $V$ is a linear subspace $W \subset V$ s.t $\pi(g)W \subset W,  \forall g \in G$

Comment: Say what?  $SU(2)$ acting on $\Bbb{C}^2$ is unitary and irreducible.  I think you're talking about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49345/unitary-representations-of-non-compact-lie-groups).

Comment: @ChadK Sorry I don't see at all what this has to do with my questions or my problem

Comment: Chad's comment is very much relevant: You are trying to prove a false statement. The question is why?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry I forgot to include that G is commutative, was that it?

Comment: Yes, this was the mistake.

Comment: That's ok, I say dumb things too like that two disjoint closed sets in a metric space have positive distance between them.  Thank you Moishe Kohan for correcting it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez No, is the first time I see representations

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Can you suggest something not to long and friendly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A representation assumes that the map $\pi:G\times V\to V$ is continuous.  So the composition $V\to \{g\}\times V\subseteq G\times V \xrightarrow{\pi} V$ is continuous.  The topologies taken are the one on $G$ as a Lie group, and on $V$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{C}$ there is a unique vector-topology compatible with the field-topology of $\Bbb{C}$.  The topology on $G\times V$ is the product topology.
2. It's shorthand for saying that $\pi(g)$ commutes with $\pi(h)$ for all $h\in G$.
3. Because each $\pi(g)$ acts as scalar-multiplication by $\lambda_g$ (dependent on $g)$.  If you restrict $\pi(g)$ to a subspace, each $\pi(g)$ is still scalar multiplication by $\lambda_g$ within the subspace.  Since every subspace is a subrepresentation, and the full representation is assumed irreducible, the only subspaces are $0$ and $V$ so $V$ must be one-dimensional (the only non-zero vector space with such property).

Comment: A linear space that has no subspaces different from 0 and iteself has to have dim=1 necesarily right? Then it looks like that can be concluded independently of the rest of the proof

Comment: @some_math_guy: A non-zero linear space that has no proper subspaces has dimension one.  That's not 'concluded'.  It's a result from linear-algebra relied upon.

Comment: Ok, so why do I need the rest of the proof to say this?

Comment: @some_math_guy: The rest of the proof shows each linear subspace is a *subrepresentation*.  That's not trivial.  subspace $\ne$ subrepresentation (usually.)

Comment: I forgot this little part in the proof :" **Hence span $\pi(G)=\Bbb C Id_V$** " that I added after Schur's lemma application. If you don't mind, why is this true and relevant?, the proof seemed to flow without writting that.

Comment: @some_math_guy:  It's true because the proof shows $\pi(G)\subseteq \Bbb{C}^* 1_V$ (where $\Bbb{C}^* = \Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$), and therefore span $\pi(G)\subseteq \Bbb{C} 1_V$, but $\Bbb{C}1_V$ is one-dimensional so they're equal.  Then every subspace $W\subseteq V$ such that $\pi(G)W\subseteq W$ must satisfy $\Bbb{C}1_V W = \Bbb{C} W=W$ so every subrepresentation is a subspace.  It's not necessary, just another way of saying the same thing and I guess the author finds it more elegant.

Comment: Regarding the first point my definition of representation does not include continuity, is it possible to show that T is continuous without that?. On the other hand if we assume a continuous representation, my definition of irreducibility says that a representation is irreducible if the only closed invariant subspaces are V  and 0, I am not sure if this changes anything

Comment: @some_math_guy:  Since you assume the representation to be a *unitary* representation, each $\pi(g)$ acts as a unitary operator on the underlying subspace $V$ which must have some inner product for 'unitary' to be defined.  A unitary operator is always continuous.

Comment: At the very end, the only subspaces are 0, and V, how do we rule out that the subspace is 0?